# Sign in with Google using .net api

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying the quick start program at [Gmail quickstart .net](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) ,
but i get an error 400, mismatched url.

I have added two localhost urls for callback but the error still persists. I know similar questions were asked before but that didn't solve my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the future it would be best if you add your code and the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Has the answer helped? Otherwise could you share more information and the code?

Comment: Unfortunately no, same error as before, the exact error is as                                                                                                                                                        Google Authorisation Error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:64673/authorize/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https.//console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthc ubkki1ofea7ok7ucj95ev114ftav71rf.apps.googleusercontent.cor project=371651884197 
Learn more

Comment: Can you share your script? Have you managed to made it work or made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

For .net the redirect uri in google developer console should be

```
http://localhost/authorize/
```

or

```
https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc
```

I think it depends on if you are using .net or .net core.

## update

> redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request

Means that the uri you are sending from is not in the list that you have added in Google developer console these uris must match.  You need to set your development environment to use a static port and then add that to your project in google developer console.

Comment: That didn't help me, It still calculates its own uri. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: what do you mean by calculates its own url?  You need to set up your development environment so that it doesn't change the port number.

Comment: It calculates on the basis on environment I guess, Local:someport. Although I am using localhost but not the port or a path that it says. I have even tried it with a hosted url but still having the same problem. For example for Auth0, it's default is sth companuname.auth0.com/login/

Comment: It depends on what development application you are using. You can set it up so that it uses a static port,  as long as the port keeps changing you cant set up your redirect uri properly fix your development application so that it uses a static port.